# how to check an exact match when checking the referer header in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I know similar questions have been asked before but I haven't been able to implement any of them successfully. I also know the security implications of using the referer header but i'm okay with that.

I have a webpage and a directory

page1.php

/content/all_of_my_content_files

I'm using iframes to access everything in the content directory but I would only like this content accessible from page1.php (no other page should be able to access this directory)

I've read the easiest way to do this is to use .htaccess in that directory to check the http_referer, except I'm not to sure on how to do this.

Essentially what I would like is to check if the http_referer exactly matches the url of page1.php and if it doesn't to redirect back to page1.php (there are security checks on page1.php that validates the user is logged in)

Comment: Could you please share URLs eg--> FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite? Just add samples ones for better understanding. Also you could share your .htaccess file too in your question.

Comment: But if you already have a session management, then why do you need any other, second mechanism for the same purpose?

Comment: it's because I have pdf files which I need to protect that I can't just add the php code to, on all the php files I've already added the redirects. I know I need to use modrewrite and I've been trying for days to figure it out. An example would be redirect FROM /content/* TO /page1.php

Comment: ^ unless the http referer matches /page1.php